# Linq query to find minimum price from a datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, datatable, console

I am working on a program using vb.net. It's a console application and I am not using a database.

I have to find the cheapest prices available for a phone number entered by user. 
The structure of datatable is pricelist(id,code,operator,price). I need to create a Linq query which can gives me the operator offering the minimum price for a desired phone number.

Comment: "pricelist(id,code,operator,code)" does not make a lot of sense with respect to your question.  Where is _price_?

Comment: Sorry the last one is Price and not code. 
I want something like this now
Dim result() As DataRow = table.Select("min(price) AND Code = " & code_passed_by_user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the `LINQ` extension methods/queries, you need an `IEnumerable`.  You can get one from a `DataTable` by calling the [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) extension method.

Then you could break your query down:

```
' Extract just the rows for the code entered by the user
Dim rowsForCode = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x("code") = userEnteredCode).ToList()
' Find the minimum price for these rows
Dim minPrice = rowsForCode.Min(Function(x) CDec(x("price")))
' Find the first row with the minimum price
Dim minRow = rowsForCode.Where(Function(x) x("price") = minPrice).First()
```

Note: If you have multiple operators offering the same price for the same code, the first one in the table will always be selected.  You could get all the matching rows (remove the `.First()` call) and pick a random one if that is an issue.

Comment: I copied this code. But in 1st line of code it gives a red line under 
"dt" and says generate a stud and when I write "priclist" the name of my datatable it says overload resolution. :/

Comment: @FaizanKarim Do you have a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` in your project and `Using System.Data` to pull in the `AsEnumerable` extension method?

Comment: Yes I have them in reference and I have also imported system.data. How can I send you my project or should i upload the code here. It is merely 4-5 methods.

Comment: @FaizanKarim You could edit the question to add the relevant code.

Comment: I mis-spelled the user entered variable name. You are a genius.